# doctrine findby magic null value

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, findby

I'm wondering if there is anyway to use doctrine's magic method to look for null values. For instance:

```
Doctrine::getTable('myClass')->findByDeletedAt(null);
```

Essentially, I want to return all records that are not deleted. I've tried the above, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Trying this gives me the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findBy() must be an array, string given

So this works for me:

```
$repository->findBy(array('date_field' => null));
```

Comment: Well, OP talks about doctrine 1, you are using doctrine 2, so the error is *normal*.

Comment: I saw >asked Oct 5 '10 at 23:45< a little late, the question is still up to date tho! :-D

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think I was trying to be to fancy. It can be done like this:

```
Doctrine::getTable('myClass')->findBy('deleted_at',null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but provided solutions are not correct for Doctrine 1.2.x

When you use functions like:

```
Doctrine::getTable('YourClass')->findByDeleted_at(null); //he want to get NOT DELETED rows!
```

Doctrine throws an error that: **"You must specify the value to findBy"**, because **null is threaten as no passed value**;

`->findBy('deleted_at', null)` throws an exception too.

`->findBy('deleted_at','NULL')` is either not correct becouse it is translated to SQL: `... WHERE deleted_at = 'NULL'`;

SQL syntax for such query should look like:

```
... WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

So the solution is to use `->findBySql()` method:

```
Doctrine::getTable('YourClass')->findBySql('deleted_at IS NULL', array());
```

* third argument could be a Hydration_Mode.

Hope that will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but your 1st attempt was incorrect. For a field 'deleted_at' you should have been doing this:

```
Doctrine::getTable('YourClass')->findByDeleted_at($val);
```

Notice I only capitalised the 1st letter of the field 'deleted_at'.

Comment: I don't think that's right mate - it camelcases the entire string.

Comment: It doesn't need to be camelcased